# Permission denied on storage/app/all_html/1658920379.blade.php. The communication protocol is not supported

Tags: laravel, permissions, storage, laravel-7, dompdf

Hi I just want to download my storage file to pdf but it show this error.
Here is my Controller

```
public function html(Request $request, $id=null){
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $html = $request->html;
        $data = [];
        if($request->hasFile('html')){
            // dd($html);
            $data['html'] = $request->file('html')->storeAs('all_html', time().'.blade.php');
            // $data['html'] = Storage::putFile('all_html', $html);  
        }
        $url = "storage/app/".$data['html'];
        $random = 'dOC'.str::random('10');
        Pdf::loadfile($url)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->setWarnings(false)->save(public_path('pdf/'.$random.'.pdf'));
        return response()->download(public_path('pdf/'.$random.'.pdf'));
    }
    return view('html');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check first in laravel storage link or not if the storage is not linked then you need to run a below command in your terminal

Storage Link command  => php artisan storage:link

then check our code and run again

If this not working then you need to check your laravel storage folder permission and give them to permission

Happy Coding!!